# Statistical evaluation metrics in Regression - What is a "mean signed difference?"

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, descriptive-statistics

Here I am with another query regarding regression model statistical measures.

In the KNIME analytics platform I am using for ML predictions, there's a statistical measure I get from evaluating the models called the "mean signed difference." Some sites explain that the MSD is the same as the MSE, or it is the deviation (standard deviation? or different). It doesn't make sense to me that MSD=MSE since their calculated values are quite different. What is their relation (if any)? Does anyone have a thought on what the MSD is an indicator of? What is it's significance in regression model evaluation?

That's all I've got :)
Thanks folks.

-Angela